# Reactjs - How use "return </Paper>" as code in my html?

Tags: reactjs, return

I want to add into my code some tags `<Paper>` and `</Paper>`. But I didn't manage to do it. These two tags farmes my html code. But, when I runed my code, it show my them as string :

```
const test = () => {

    const paperStyleTop = (nameMinistry) => {

        if (nameMinistry === "justice"
        ) {
            return `<Paper elevation={3} sx={{ ...(alertError && { border: "2px solid rgba(255,0,0,0.5)" }) }}>`
        } else {
            return `<Paper elevation={3}>`
        }

    }

    const paperStyleBottom = () => {
        return `</Paper>;`
    }

    const arrayMinistries = [
        {
            icon: "balance",
            nameMinistry: "Justice",
            id: "mJustice",
            useStateFullName: ministers.justice.fullName
        },
        {
            icon: "local_police",
            nameMinistry: "Intérieur",
            id: "mInterieur",
            useStateFullName: ministers.interieur.fullName
        }
    ]

return (

    {arrayMinistries.map((ministry) => (
        <Grid item}>

            {paperStyleTop(ministry.nameMinistry)}

            // Html code...

            {paperStyleBottom()}

        </Grid>
    ))}
)

export default test;
```

Could you explain to me how I can do to add these pieces of lines to my code ?

************** SOLUTION ***************
With that propose below it dit like this and that work :

```
const test = () => {

    const paperProps = (nameMinistry) => {

        const props = {
                    elevation: 3,
                };

        if (nameMinistry === "mJustice" ||
            nameMinistry === "mInterieur" ||
            nameMinistry === "mEducationNationale" ||
            nameMinistry === "mSante" ||
            nameMinistry === "mArmees" ||
            nameMinistry === "mEconomieFinance"
        ) {
            props.sx = { ...(alertError && { border: "2px solid rgba(255,0,0,0.5)" }) };
        } else {
            props.sx = {}
        }
        return props;
    }

    const arrayMinistries = [
        {
            icon: "balance",
            nameMinistry: "Justice",
            id: "mJustice",
            useStateFullName: ministers.justice.fullName
        },
        {
            icon: "local_police",
            nameMinistry: "Intérieur",
            id: "mInterieur",
            useStateFullName: ministers.interieur.fullName
        }
    ]

return (

    {arrayMinistries.map((ministry) => (
        <Grid item}>

            <Paper {...paperProps(ministry.id)}>

            // Html code...

            </Paper>

        </Grid>
    ))}
)

export default test;
```

Comment: Can you add a minimal working prototype of your code? You can use codesandbox.io for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like an XY problem to me. It appears that you want to pass specific props into your `<Paper>` component: what don't you object spread the props dictionary into it instead?

You can use `useMemo()` to memoize the props you want to spread, so that the object will be updated based on changes in the dependency array.

Example:

```
const test = () => {

    const paperProps = useMemo(() => {
        const props = {
            elevation: 3,
        };

        if (ministry.nameMinistry === 'justice') {
            props.sx = { ...(alertError && { border: "2px solid rgba(255,0,0,0.5)" }) };
        }

        return props;
    }, [ministry.nameMinistry])

    return (
        <Grid item>
            <Paper {...paperProps}>
                {/* More content here */}    
            </Paper>
        </Grid>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I forget to mention that in my code the `ministry.nameMinistry` was provid by a `.map` *(I updated my post to mention that)*.
So what I have to do now to make that work ?

Comment: @Renjus From a map but where? And how?

Comment: ok I updated my exemple with the array inside. I hope that will help you.